# Create bootable USB drive on Mac for Windows

Tags: windows, live-usb, usb-drive, mac

I need to create a bootable USB drive for Ubuntu for a Windows machine, but I got a Mac... How can I make a bootable USB on a Mac, for a Windows machine?

Comment: @zwets, no, I think the instructions in that link are for creating a bootable USB to be used on a Mac (i.e. to create a USB to install Ubuntu on a Mac; target machine is Mac).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just follow the standard instructions on the [Ubuntu Download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). The USB stick you create on the Mac will boot the PC.

After the USB has been written your Mac may give the warning "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer". You can safely ignore that warning and proceed with step 9, eject the USB.

Answer (score 1):

Unetbootin is available for the MAC [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)